# Chrome Developer Tools becoming "undockable"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Since recently (I think since I updated Chrome to 59 Beta) some pages open Developer Tools as a separate popup window instead of as a docked view at the bottom of my screen. When I try to re-dock it I can't find the necessary menu:

[image: missing dock menu on an undocked dev tools]

On some pages however it seems to work correctly and opens Developer Tools correctly docked. If I look for the dock options here I can find them without a problem:

[image: dock menu exists if dev tools are already docked]

Is this just me or is anyone else experiencing these problems? I couldn't find anything on Chrome's bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known regression that has been fixed. Wait a little bit and the problem will eventually go away when Chrome updates.

Crbug defaults to "open issues" when you search, perhaps you were filtering out fixed issues.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=717003

Comment: Oh, thanks! That's entirely possible, it's a bit of a weird search interface.